# logstash import csv file using config file on windows

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to import a csv file to create data on my elasticsearch server in order to test it.

but I'm blocked to importing data using config file

this is a command (on winodws) logstash -f file.config

this is my config file

---

```
input{
    file {  
            path => "‪/E:/Formation/kibana/data/cars.csv"
            start_position => "beginning"
            sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}
filter{
    csv{
        separator => ","
        columns => ["maker","model","mileage","manufacture_year","engine_displacement",
        "engine_power","body_type","color_slug","stk_year","transimission","door_count",
        "seat_count","fuel_type","date_created","date_last_seen","price_eur"]
    }
    mutate {
        convert => ["mileage","integer"]
        convert => ["price_eur","float"]
        convert => ["engine_power","integer"]
        convert => ["door_count","integer"]
        convert => ["seat_count","integer"]
    }

}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost"
    index => "cars"
    document_type=> "sold_cars"
  }
  stdout { }
}
```

and this is the error
 **UPDATE** this is log after using mode --debug thanks for helping

```
16:49:29.252 [Ruby-0-Thread-11: E:/Formation/kibana/logstash-5.4.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:532] DEBUG logstash.pipeline - Pushing flush onto pipeline
16:49:34.257 [Ruby-0-Thread-11: E:/Formation/kibana/logstash-5.4.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:532] DEBUG logstash.pipeline - Pushing flush onto pipeline
16:49:39.257 [Ruby-0-Thread-11: E:/Formation/kibana/logstash-5.4.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:532] DEBUG logstash.pipeline - Pushing flush onto pipeline
16:49:43.663 [[main]<file] DEBUG logstash.inputs.file - _globbed_files: /e/Formation/kibana/data/cars.csv: glob is: []
```

Comment: You simply need to remove the first slash in your path and simply have `E:/Formation/...`

Comment: now I correct the probleme of the path 

but its working without any results (any index is created )

Comment: in your `stdout` output can you add `codec => rubydebug` to make sure something's coming out?

Comment: I got some logs and at the end I got this 13:44:20.158 [Api Webserver] INFO  logstash.agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600} but nothing changed after adding codec in output

Comment: Oh I known the issue, the sincedb_path on Windows cannot be `/dev/null` :-) Put a real Windows path

Comment: path of wich folder or file ?

Comment: Whichever you choose... can be `E:/Formation/kibana/sincedb` for instance

Comment: What happens if you choose a proper sincedb_path ?

Comment: It works funny but no data are indexing into elasticsearch ? I dont understand why !

Comment: Can you launch logstash with the `--debug` switch and paste the output you get?

Comment: please see update (with logs)

Comment: Can you use the following path instead: `E:\\Formation\\kibana\\data\\cars.csv`? Also what is the last-modified timestamp of your CSV file?

Comment: when I use the path E:\\Formation\\kibana\\data\\cars.csv I get error about absolute path.

the last modified date 2017/03/16 21:34

Comment: What about my second question?

Comment: when I use the path E:\\Formation\\kibana\\data\\cars.csv I get error about absolute path. the last modified date 2017/03/16 21:34

Comment: that's it, you can either touch the file or add `ignore_older => 31556926` (seconds in one year)

Comment: I got this logs repeating infinitly please see update

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you should use `sincedb_path => "nul"` instead of `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"`, which is used on Linux-based operating systems.